# Scala parser combinators parsing xml?

Tags: xml, parsing, scala

Can scala's parser combinators parse xml and validate that the closing tags have the same name as the opening tags? I don't directly need it, but I would like to know the limits of my libraries.

Comment: I'm not shure but i believe the scala.xml Library checks also the closing tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can do that. Use `into` or `>>` (which is the same thing, really) to parameterize a latter parser based on a parsed value.

Answer (score 3):

This document seem to describe an attempt on that: http://www.berniepope.id.au/docs/scala_parser_combinators.pdf

... and a link to the software (Scala XML-parser): http://www.berniepope.id.au/software.html

Comment: Part of the idea was that the parser would validate the end tags, which it doesn't.

Comment: Dead links for the software as of this writing.

Comment: Are you sure? Works now

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in [XML pickler combinators](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-scala-client/wiki/DevelopersGuide#XML_Pickler_Combinators), part of the GData Scala client library.  I've pulled out the pickler combinators and made them available in a self-contained library [here](https://bitbucket.org/anovstrup/xml-pickler-combinators).