# Scala combinator parser, what does >> mean?

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I am little bit confusing about ">>" in scala. Daniel said in [Scala parser combinators parsing xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271010/scala-parser-combinators-parsing-xml) that it could be used to parameterize the parser base on result from previous parser. Could someone give me some example/hint ? I already read scaladoc but still not understand it.

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I said, it serves to parameterize a parser, but let's walk through an example to make it clear.

Let's start with a simple parser, that parses a number follow by a word:

```
def numberAndWord = number ~ word
def number        = "\\d+".r
def word          = "\\w+".r
```

Under [RegexParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers), this will parse stuff like "3 fruits".

Now, let's say you also want a list of what these "n things" are. For example, "3 fruits: banana, apple, orange". Let's try to parse that to see how it goes.

First, how do I parse "N" things? As it happen, there's a `repN` method:

```
def threeThings = repN(3, word)
```

That will parse "banana apple orange", but not "banana, apple, orange". I need a separator. There's `repsep` that provides that, but that won't let me specify how many repetitions I want. So, let's provide the separator ourselves:

```
def threeThings = word ~ repN(2, "," ~> word)
```

Ok, that words. We can write the whole example now, for three things, like this:

```
def listOfThings = "3" ~ word ~ ":" ~ threeThings
def word         = "\\w+".r
def threeThings  = word ~ repN(2, "," ~> word)
```

That kind of works, except that I'm fixing "N" in 3. I want to let the user specify how many. And that's where `>>`, also known as `into` (and, yes, it is `flatMap` for `Parser`), comes into. First, let's change `threeThings`:

```
def things(n: Int) = n match {
  case 1          => word ^^ (List(_))
  case x if x > 1 => word ~ repN(x - 1, "," ~> word) ^^ { case w ~ l => w :: l }
  case x          => err("Invalid repetitions: "+x)
}
```

This is slightly more complicated than you might have expected, because I'm forcing it to return `Parser[List[String]]`. But how do I pass a parameter to things? I mean, this won't work:

```
def listOfThings = number ~ word ~ ":" ~ things(/* what do I put here?*/)
```

But we can rewrite that like this:

```
def listOfThings = (number ~ word <~ ":") >> {
  case n ~ what => things(n.toInt)
}
```

That is almost good enough, except that I now lost `n` and `what`: it only returns "List(banana, apple, orange)", not how many there ought to be, and what they are. I can do that like this:

```
def listOfThings   = (number ~ word <~ ":") >> {
  case n ~ what => things(n.toInt) ^^ { list => new ~(n.toInt, new ~(what, list)) }
}
def number         = "\\d+".r
def word           = "\\w+".r
def things(n: Int) = n match {
  case 1          => word ^^ (List(_))
  case x if x > 1 => word ~ repN(x - 1, "," ~> word) ^^ { case w ~ l => w :: l }
  case x          => err("Invalid repetitions: "+x)
}
```

Just a final comment. You might have wondered asked yourself *"what do you mean `flatMap`? Isn't that a monad/for-comprehension thingy?"* Why, yes, and yes! :-) Here's another way of writing `listOfThings`:

```
def listOfThings   = for {
  nOfWhat  <- number ~ word <~ ":"
  n ~ what = nOfWhat
  list     <- things(n.toInt)
}  yield new ~(n.toInt, new ~(what, list))
```

I'm not doing `n ~ what <- number ~ word <~ ":"` because that uses `filter` or `withFilter` in Scala, which is not implemented by `Parsers`. But here's even another way of writing it, that doesn't have the exact same semantics, but produce the same results:

```
def listOfThings   = for {
  n    <- number
  what <- word
  _    <- ":" : Parser[String]
  list <- things(n.toInt)
}  yield new ~(n.toInt, new ~(what, list))
```

This might even give one to think that maybe the claim that *"monads are everywhere"* might have something to it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but just one more thing. I still don't understand about new in { list => new ~(n.toInt, new ~(what, list)) }
}. I'm still relatively new to scala so I only knew about using new for generate instance from class.

Comment: @Tg. That is exactly what is happening here. When you parse something with the `~` operator, the result will be an instance of the [`~` class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$tilde). I could have -- arguably, I should have -- returned a tuple instead -- it _is_ easier. However, I wanted to preserve the original return value in the example code.

Comment: @Tg. Not true. Scala has functions which are objects. Here, however, the `~` class and `Parser`'s `~` operator have the same name by design, and `~`, the operator, returns a `Parser[~[T,U]]`, where `T` and `U` are the types of the parsers this operator applies to. However, class and operator could have entirely different names. By the way, this duality operator/class can also be found with `::`.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. It seems like I am still having much to learn. but yeah, what I really meant in previous comment is "I was mistaken a ~ for normal operator" so it confused me first time.

Answer (score 5):

The method `>>` takes a function that is given the result of the parser and uses it to contruct a new parser. As stated, this can be used to parameterize a parser on the result of a previous parser.

## Example

The following parser parses a line with `n + 1` integer values. The first value `n` states the number of values to follow. This first integer is parsed and then the result of this parse is used to construct a parser that parses `n` further integers.

#### Parser definition

The following line assumes, that you can parse an integer with `parseInt: Parser[Int]`. It first parses an integer value `n` and then uses `>>` to parse `n` additional integers which form the result of the parser. So the initial `n` is not returned by the parser (though it's the size of the returned list).

```
def intLine: Parser[Seq[Int]] = parseInt >> (n => repN(n,parseInt))
```

#### Valid inputs

```
1 42
3 1 2 3
0
```

#### Invalid inputs

```
0 1
1
3 42 42
```

Comment: Isn't that an alias for flatMap ?

Comment: @paradigmatic According to the scaladocs, it's an alias for `into`. According to the sources, `>>` calls `into`, which calls `flatMap`.